# Creating HttpComponentsMessageSender with httpClient

Tags: java, spring, soap, httpclient, kerberos

I can't authorize to SOAP server using kerberos.
Here's my configuration code

```
  @Bean
  def webServiceTemplate(): WebServiceTemplate = {
    val webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate()
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller.marshaller)
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller.marshaller)
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(Parameters.getDefaultURI)
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender())
    webServiceTemplate
  }

@Bean
  def httpComponentsMessageSender(): HttpComponentsMessageSender = {
    val sender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender()
    if(Parameters.isProduction){
      sender.setHttpClient(getHttpClient())
    } else sender.setCredentials(usernamePasswordCredentials())
    sender
  }

  @Bean
  def usernamePasswordCredentials(): NTCredentials = {
    new NTCredentials(
       "usr",
       "pass",
      "",
      "MY_COMPANY"
    )
  }

  @Bean
  def getHttpClient() = {
    val builder = HttpClientBuilder.create
    val authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.create[AuthSchemeProvider]
      .register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory(true)).build
    builder.setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry)
    builder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(getCredProvider())
    builder.addInterceptorFirst(new RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor())
    builder.build
  }
```

My HttpClient can make requests to other kerberized services like oozie. However when working with SOAP server I get

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized [401]
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:699)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:609)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378)
```

I use krb5module and make request as follows

```
reply = Subject.doAs(subject, new PrivilegedExceptionAction[CreateReply]() {
          @throws[Exception]
          override def run: CreateReply = getWebServiceTemplate
            .marshalSendAndReceive("http://my-soap-service", request)
            .asInstanceOf[CreateReply]
```

How can I authorize to SOAP service? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So my Idea behind this is using valid, working httpClient to configure HttpComponentsMessageSender. Is it possible at all? If not, how should I handle kerberos auth then?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was using wrong path(http://my-soap-service). I changed to valid one and could authorize.

**Conclusion:** HttpClient properties can help to set up HttpComponentsMessageSender for SAOP.